# Show that $n$ is a prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\geq2$ and $(G,.)$ an abelian group of order $n$, with the property that for any $a\in G$, the number of endomorphisms of $G$ with $f(a)=a$ is equal to $n+1-ord(a)$, where $ord(a)$ is the order of $a$. Show that $n$ is a prime number.

My approach is to suppose that $n$ is not prime, so there is a decomposition for $n=p_1p_2...p_k$, where $p_1,\dots ,p_k$ are prime numbers and from Cauchy's theorem there is an $a\in G$ such  that $ord(a)=p_i$. Now $f(e)=f(a^{p_i})=(f(a))^{p_i}=e$, and so the number of endomorphisms $f$ is $n+1-1=n$.

However, from the hypothesis, the number of $f$ is $n+1-p_i$, and so $n+1-p_i=n$ $\Rightarrow p_i=1$. As we chosen $p_i$ arbitrarily, we get that all the numbers $p_i,i\in{0,1,...,k}$ are $1\Rightarrow n=1$, false with $n\geq2$.

> Is my proof correct?

Comment: The problem seems ill-formed- wouldn't $f(e)=e$ always hold for any endomorphism fixing an element (regardless of the primality of $|G|$)?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 but that needs to hold for all elements.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't used the hypothesis that the group is abelian.

I corrected some points of grammar & punctuation, though, too, like not starting a sentence with a mathematical symbol, adding a space after each comma, *etc.*

Comment: Thanks! How should I use the fact that the group is abelian?

Comment: Based on what I understand, you don't need that hypothesis. This is a bad sign though. I'm inclined to think I'm wrong. Where is the problem from, @JacobDenicula?

Comment: A mathematical magazine. It doesn`t matter as it has no proof.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't, epistemologically, @JacobDenicula. (Try to use ' instead of ` on this site for technical reasons.) If it has no proof, it has no proof. But to see whether it's likely to be correct, it helps to know from whence it came.

Comment: Using that apostrophe `does this` when used either side of a string of symbols.